# How to tell if my VM is Gen1 or Gen2 in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I would like to figure out if my Azure VM (Windows + Linux) is Gen1 or Gen2. Ideally I want to get this to work via `az cli` or from the actual server itself. I have tried `az vm list -g RG-Name -d` but it does not really display this information. Does anyone know how to obtain this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question. The [hyperVgeneration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get#hypervgenerationtype) property in the VM's instance view information exposes this detail about the VM, wherein **V1** indicates Generation 1 VMs and **V2** indicates Generation 2 VMs.

Using the [az vm get-instance-view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_get_instance_view), you could try:

```
az vm get-instance-view -g <rg-name> -n <vm-name>
```

and look for the `hyperVgeneration` property in the response:

```
{
...
  "instanceView": {
    "maintenanceRedeployStatus": null,
    "computerName": "gen2-BA",
    ...
    "hyperVgeneration": "V2",
    ...
    "osName": "Windows Server 2019 Datacenter",
    "osVersion": "Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0",
  },
...
}
```

Going one step ahead, if you want to query your Subscription for Gen1/Gen2 VMs, you can execute the following Azure CLI command:

```
az vm get-instance-view --ids $(az vm list --query "[].id" -o tsv) --query '[].{VMName:name, OS:storageProfile.osDisk.osType, SKU:storageProfile.imageReference.sku, HyperVgeneration:instanceView.hyperVgeneration}' -o table
```

The response would be similar to:
[image: List VMs]

Although the Gen2 VMs' SKU names also hint towards the Gen1 vs Gen2 distinction, `hyperVgeneration` should be the exact property to look for.

Comment: What's the equivalent of this in AZ Powershell?

Comment: @shadowz1337 Can you try [Get-AzVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-8.0.0#code-try-5)?

Comment: I got it working.

`$Status = Get-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $VMInfo.ResourceGroupName -Name $($VM.Name) -Status`

`$VM_Generation = $Status.HyperVGeneration`